# THREAD WARNING: ['Camera'] took '290.006104' ms. Plugin should use a background thread

Tags: ios, cordova, camera, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I am building a `Phonegap` app for IOS. I have used `Cordova` camera `plugin` for profile pic upload. My sample code is:

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(that.imageDataSuccessCallback, that.imageDataErrorCallback, { quality: 10, destinationType: 1, encodingType: 0, allowEdit: true, correctOrientation: true, sourceType:0 });
```

When I click on that particular button I am getting warning as

```
THREAD WARNING: ['Camera'] took '290.006104' ms. Plugin should use a background thread.
```

It is blocking my app. Can any one please suggest how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 8):

I'm not sure that you should be concerned about `290ms` but if you are, you can do the following:

Since `navigator.camera.getPicture()` in `Camera.js` is calling the `-(void)takePicture:(CDVInvokeUrlCommand*)command` method in `CDVCamera.m` you will have to add **threading** there.

Open `CDVCamera.m` and add the following before the first line of `takePicture` method:

```
[self.commandDelegate runInBackground:^{
```

end add this after the last line:

```
}];
```

so it should look like this:

```
- (void)takePicture:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command
{
    [self.commandDelegate runInBackground:^{
        NSString* callbackId = command.callbackId;
        NSArray* arguments = command.arguments;

        ...
        ...
        ...

        self.hasPendingOperation = YES;
    }];
}
```

Here is a reference for building Cordova plugins using background mode [look for **THREADING**](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/edge/guide_platforms_ios_plugin.md.html#iOS%20Plugins):